# Looping through child elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following classes defined in my typescript file

```
class A{
    description: string;
    bArr: B[];
}

class B{
    nouns: string[];
    tokens: string[];
}
```

i am trying to print the value of tokens in class B but i am not able to it's giving me error.
This is what i have tried yet :

```
tableData : A[] = [];
/*
    Initialize tableData
*/
this.tableData.forEach( data => {
        data.bArr.forEach(
          b => {
            console.log(b.tokens);
          }
        )
      })
```

but i get error => for is not a function  when i am trying to run. I am able to print the members of A but when i try to access class B members.

Comment: I think you meant the 'class' to be an 'interface'?

Comment: I suppose,  in some cases `data.bArr` is not array, you need check it before calling forEach

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `this` keyword here. This is working fine to me.

**TS**

```
class A{
    description: string[];
    bArr: B[];
}

class B{
    nouns: string[];
    tokens: string[];
}

const tableData: A[] = [
  {
    description: ['asda'],
    bArr: [
      {
        nouns: ['23', '23'],
        tokens: ['sdad']
      }]
  }];


tableData.forEach( data => {
   data.bArr.forEach(
     b => {
       console.log(b.tokens);
     }
   );
})
```

**JS**

```js
"use strict";
class A {
}
class B {
}
const tableData = [
    {
        description: ['asda'],
        bArr: [
            {
                nouns: ['23', '23'],
                tokens: ['sdad']
            }
        ]
    }
];
tableData.forEach(data => {
    data.bArr.forEach(b => {
        console.log(b.tokens);
    });
});
```

Comment: i can directly print b.tokens but what to do if i want to print individual elements?

Comment: What you mean by individual element? each token instead of array?